# CKEditor insert empty paragraph

Tags: dom, ckeditor

In the CKEditor plugin I'm writing, i need to create a new empty paragraph.

I know that empty paragraphs (`<p></p>`) are collapsed by most browsers, that is why CKEditor has some special handling for them:

- When displaying the HTML source, CKEditor displays `<p>&nbsp;</p>` for an empty paragraph (for example, when you press enter twice)
- Depending on the browser, in the editing area CKEditor fills the Paragraph with another placeholder. For example in Mozilla Firefox, it inserts a `<br type="_moz" />` into the paragraph.

However, when inserting a `p` DOM node manually (using the CKEditor dom object), this special handling is omitted. It magically appears when i switch to source view and back edit mode, though.

I've tried:

```
var new_p = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('p');
editor.insertElement(new_p);
```

And:

```
var new_p = new CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml('<p></p>');
editor.insertElement(new_p);
```

And also:

```
editor.insertHtml('<p>');
```

But the special handling of the empty paragraph does not take place. I get an empty Paragraph, but as the Browser is collapsing it, I can't see or edit its content correctly.

When switching back and forth to the source code view, CKEditor detects the empty paragraph and inserts the filler. Also when submitting the data. But i need the filler to appear immediately when inserting the new node.

**How do i get CKEditor to handle my new paragraph like any other empty paragraph it would create when a user hits Enter twice?**

I know i could also insert `&nbsp;` manually as HTML content to the new DOM node, but thats a huge difference - because in this case, the space really appears in the editing area, so when a user enters content into the new paragraph, he must delete the non-breaking space manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching how CKEditor handles the press of [ENTER] internally, i came to this solution:

```
var new_node = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( 'p' );

// insert UTF-16 non-breaking space
var dummy = editor.document.createText( '\u00A0' );
dummy.appendTo( new_node );
editor.insertElement(new_node);

// move cursor to beginning of new element
var range = editor.createRange();
range.moveToPosition( new_node, CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_START );
editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ range ] );
```